# seeing the PHP output

Tags: php, html

I have this simple HTML form. and A php script in my computer,

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="file:///home/tamim/welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And my welcome.php is

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

but when I submit., firefox gives me a prompt of what should it do with the welcome.php file? How do I run the php file on submit and see the output in commandline or browser or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action should not be file path.It should be like

```
<form action="http://localhost/your_proj_folder/welcome.php" method="post">
```

You can place your IP instead of localhost (and considering that tamim is your folder name where you have placed these files then place your folder name tamim after the localhost)

Comment: This is assuming the OP is running a local webserver - which I would tend to doubt, considering the fact that he's starting with a `file://` link.

Comment: It says "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost." will it be like this? 
    "<form action="http://localhost/home/welcome.php" method="post">

Comment: then you need to check your localhost.if you are a windows then you need to use XAMPP server as local server..

Comment: I am using UBUNTU,, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

TO execute a `PHP` file, you have to put it on a `server` where `PHP` installed.

If you are using windows, you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) as local server

Comment: I am using UBUNTU,, what should I do?

Comment: @TamimAdDari: **(If you are using windows, you can use WAMP)** or XAMPP as local server

Comment: @TamimAdDari: download and install xampp

Answer (score 1):

Remove file:///home/tamim/. Just welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

are you running it in local server like XAMPP or WAMP . you have to keep this file in localserver Ex:if you are using wampp keep this file in htdocs  and then run.